# Refactor deeply nested Rust `Result`s and `Option`s handling into a more functional style

Tags: git, rust, functional-programming

I have this monstrosity of nested code in Rust, which works fine.

The idea is to open a git repo's local config data-structure if possible, otherwise just return an empty `GitConfig`. There are a series of calls that are required to find the current directory, search up from it for a git repo, open the repo, and then open the config within it, all of which could either throw an error, or return `None`. I don't care what error is thrown, (or when `None` is returned) except that when an error is thrown (or `None` *is* returned), an empty GitConfig is returned from the entire chain.

```rust
       let local = match env::current_dir() {
            Err(_) => GitConfig::new().unwrap(),
            Ok(cwd) => {
                match find_git_root(&cwd) {
                    None => GitConfig::new().unwrap(),
                    Some(git_path) => {
                        match Repository::open(&git_path) {
                            Err(_) => GitConfig::new().unwrap(),
                            Ok(repo) => {
                                match repo.config() {
                                    Err(_) => GitConfig::new().unwrap(),
                                    Ok(config) => {
                                        config.open_level(Local).unwrap()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

I am trying to refactor this into a more functional style with the use of combinators like `map()` `and_then()` and others but I'm having a stack overflow in my head trying to figure it out. I'm sure there is a way of doing this, taking into account the return types of both `Result` and `Options` in the chain, and also the fact that the concrete `Error` types within the `Result`s vary from call to call.

Is there a nice, idiomatic way of writing this functionally, while passing any error down the chain so that it can be handled at the very end with an `ok_or_else()` or `map_or_else()` or similar? And how might I flatten the nesting to make the code look cleaner and be more easy to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are crates like [`mdo`](https://crates.io/crates/mdo) or [`map_for`](https://crates.io/crates/map_for) that allow you to simplify this code into something like:

```
map_for!{
    cwd <- env::current_dir().ok();
    git_path <- find_git_root (&cwd);
    repo <- Repository::open (&git_path).ok();
    config <- repo.config().ok();
    => config.open_level(Local).unwrap()
}.unwrap_or_else (|| GitConfig::new().unwrap());
```

Or you can do it with the `?` operator and a function (or closure):

```
(|| {
    let cwd = env::current_dir().ok()?;
    let git_path = find_git_root (&cwd)?;
    let repo = Repository::open (&git_path).ok()?;
    let config = repo.config().ok()?;
    config.open_level(Local).ok()
})().unwrap_or_else (|| GitConfig::new().unwrap());
```

Eventually, you should be able to do it with a [`try` block](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html), but those are unstable for the time being.

Full disclosure: I am the author of the `map_for` crate.

Comment: Thanks! These look cool, but, for the second option, I'm still getting:

the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)

Comment: I removed the `unwrap()` from the second last line in the lower example and that seems to improve things, but now I'm getting this for the top two `let`s : the trait `std::convert::From<std::option::NoneError>` is not implemented for `git2::error::Error` -- It looks as if it doesn't like `?`...

Comment: @Brad the `unwrap` you removed should have been replaced with an `ok`, see fixed answer.